# Highcharts Maps - Rounded zoom buttons

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts API for a project. Everything works fine but I have one problem. I want the zoom in/out buttons to be rounded. I've tried border-radius 50%, changing the r value on mapNavigation.buttonOptions.theme, but none of those worked out for me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you share your code and what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

use `mapNavigation.buttonOptions.theme.r` for adjusting the border radius

```js
mapNavigation: {
   enabled: true,
   buttonOptions: {
       theme: {
          r: 8, // change border radius here
       },
       verticalAlign: 'bottom'
   }
},
```

[image]

Code and Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j8213ymh/2/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this gives the button's wrapper a border radius. I need to give each button a border radius, so that they become circles instead of squares.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own SVG path for the buttons by overwritting `topbutton` and `bottombutton` in `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols`. Below is an example for circles:

```
(function(H) {
    function selectiveRoundedRect(x, y, w, h, r) {
        var xStart = x + w / 2 - r,
            yStart = y + h / 2 - r;

        return [
            ['M', xStart, yStart],
            // top side
            ['A', r, r, 0, 0, 0, xStart + 2 * r, yStart + 2 * r],
            // top right corner
            ['A', r, r, 0, 0, 0, xStart, yStart]
        ];
    }
    H.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.topbutton = function(x, y, w, h, options) {
        var r = (options && options.r) || 0;
        return selectiveRoundedRect(x - 1, y - 1, w, h, r);
    };
    H.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.bottombutton = function(x, y, w, h, options) {
        var r = (options && options.r) || 0;
        return selectiveRoundedRect(x - 1, y - 1, w, h, r);
    };
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hwg9up7f/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts